# Cannot connect to a Zookeeper instance from another machine

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have a simple Kafka installation running with the default Zookeeper. I can send & consume messages from the same server where it is installed. I can also send messages to the Kafka servers from an external server. But when i try to connect the Kafka consumer from the same external server, I see this error every 20 seconds.

> [2017-12-13 19:51:28,797] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 20000ms for sessionid 0x16053254a360001 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)

The Zookeeper config file is the default one, with following settings.

```
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
maxClientCnxns=0
```

Are there any tips to troubleshoot this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you telnet or ping  to both kafka and zookeeper from external server?

Comment: I can telnet & ping to the Kafka & zookeeper servers.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was because of firewall access. The firewall was restricted to allow incoming traffic, but outgoing traffic was blocked. After the port 2181 was made accessible, I can now connect to the Zookeeper.